# execute a function if everything is received, MPI C

Tags: c, mpi

with MPI, in C, how can I execute a function if and only if I received all data from N processors, in my master process ID 0?

edit: Is there a way of receiving also all data in the same order than they have been sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question correctly [MPI_Reduce](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Reduce.html) is what you need.

EDIT: so I did not get your question correctly. What you do need is [MPI_Gather](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.5/man3/MPI_Gather.3.php). And in this document you see that: `Each process (root process included) sends the contents of its send buffer to the root process. The root process receives the messages and stores them in rank order.` Hope this answers your question.

Comment: but, will MPI_Reduce take care of the send order?

Comment: You mean will it be executed only when all the data is sent? Yes that is what will happen unless an error occurs in MPI.

Comment: `MPI_Reduce` will perform a reduction operation among a communicator. If you need to receive data from N processes into a single process then I think you are searching for `MPI_Gather`.

Comment: @Massimiliano but what he wants is to execute a function with all the data from all the processors. Isn't that what reduce is all about? [example](https://rqchp.ca/modules/cms/checkFileAccess.php?file=local.rqchpweb_udes/mpi/exemples_cpp/ex12_Reduce_EN.cpp)

Comment: @izomorphius I understood it differently: he wants to execute a function "if and only if he received all data from N processors". I don't think this implies he want to execute the same function on all the data. If the case is the one you thought, then you are right: reduction will save space and time.

Comment: @Massimiliano that is why I say - "If I get your question correctly"

Comment: It will be the same function, but on different part of data. The process 0 will wait until he will receive all data and will print out a matrix. Each processor need to compute the same function, but on different rows. The process 0 will merge the output. It's the reason why the order is important for me..

Answer (score 1):

Try to have a look at the [MPI_Gather](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Gather.html) function. After the call you can check for the conditional execution in this way:

```
if (ierr == MPI_SUCCESS) {
  // Execute a function
}
```

Comment: Will MPI_Gather place the part in the same order as they have been sent?

Comment: From the standard 2.2, section 5.5 on MPI_Gather: _The root process receives the messages and stores them in rank order._

Comment: Checking the return value of `MPI_Gather` is pointless unless the error handler for the communicator was changed to `MPI_ERRORS_RETURN` (which I doubt most people would even bother or know how to do). The default error handler calls `MPI_Abort()` on error and the next line of code would not execute at all.